# "How to create a new variable from an existing variable in a for loop in R?"

Tags: r, loops, rstudio

I have recently encountered an error message upon running my for loop as follows:

**Error: object 'Month1' not found**

```
res_org<-read.csv("XXX", sep=",", header=TRUE)
dim(res_org)
exp<-res_org
head(res_org)

exp1<-res_org
dim(exp1)

n<-length(exp1$Longitude)
i=1

for (i in 1:n){

   exp$Month1<-c()
   exp$Year1<-c()

   Month1[i]<-exp$Month[i] - 1
   if(Month1[i]<=0){
     (exp1[i, 'Year1'] =(exp1$Year[i]-1))& 
     (exp1[i, 'Month1']=(exp1$Month[i]-1+12))
   }
   else{
     (exp1[i, 'Year1'] = exp1$Year[i]) &
     (exp1[i, 'Month1']= (exp1$Month[i] - 1))
   }
}

head(exp1)

write.csv(exp1, file = "XXX")
```

It just seem very odd to me that R is not creating another new `Month1` variable based on my specification: `Month1[i]<-exp$Month[i] - 1` even though I have the  variables for 'Month' and 'Year' in the imported dataset.

Purpose of the above for loop:

The goal is to subtract a single interval from each month (i = 1, 2, 3,...12) while simultaneously modifying the year for the purpose of effectively preparing the annual average calculations through the subsequent kriging imputation.

For example, at an interval of one, December (12) will be converted into November (11), February (2) will be converted into January (1), January (1) will be converted into December (12), and so on. Likewise, at an interval of two, December (12) will be converted into October (10), February (2) will be converted into December (12), January (1) will be converted into November (11), and so on and so forth.

Regarding the years, all years should remain the same except for scenarios when certain months in a year are converted to previous months in a past year (e,g, at an interval of one, if January (1) becomes December (12), the year would subsequently change to the previous year ; at an interval of two, if February (2) becomes December (12) or January (1) becomes November (11), the year would subsequently change to the previous year as well.

So, I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could potentially offer a solution to the above error message or even provide another for loop to achieve my goal as discussed above. Thank you in advance!

Best,

Lisa

Comment: you need to create month1 before the loop like you do with n. this is the line it doesn't like: `Month1[i]<-exp$Month[i] - 1`. Just create month1 to be an empty vector the length of your loop

Comment: also, whats going on with the if statemtent? Why do you have a & sign in there? what do you want to happen inside the if/else blocks?

Comment: You certainly do NOT want to execute `exp$Month1<-c()` or `exp$Year1<-c()` inside the loop. If that succeeds it will erase every step except the last one.

Comment: @RAB:  I really appreciate your responses to my earlier for loop issue; however, I have already resolved this issue with the assistance of a senior R programmer.